# Code to toggle classes not working as expected in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm taking baby steps with jQuery and I do not want to mess with what I have created.

This piece of code toggle classes that opens and closes multiple `div` tags on a single page.
I have about 5 `div` tags that are hidden and this code toggle the classes to open them sequentially; they are not all opened at the same time.

The problem is, I just tested the page in Chrome and it does not open on the first click regardless of which tab I click first. I have to click twice. However the code works in FF, IE, Safari.I am thinking this is a problem with the Index starting at `0`, not sure.

Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.readMore').each(function(i) {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('readMore readLess');
            $(this).next().toggle();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `$(this).next().toggle();`? Each `.readMore` element is associated with another element immediately following that does not have the class `readMore` and gets toggled as well?

Comment: Can you post an example on jsFiddle on add your HTML here?

Comment: As I mentioned, I have multiple div tags that I need to open. The only other way I know how to do this is to create individual function with separate div tag ID for each instances.

Comment: Here is an example on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AWS52/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/8sXBE/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.readMore').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('readLess');            
  });    
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Adil's answer, but more in line with your specification (toggling each following div, that is):

http://jsfiddle.net/JBLjh/2/

Comment: I have tried all the examples above and the problem still exists. Basically I have the Readmore link over each hidden content: The code does not work in Chrome but in all other Browser. - Thanks everyone!

Comment: Not sure if this will change anything, but what if you try delegating the events? (syntax: `$(parent_selector).on(event, selector, function)`; example: http://jsfiddle.net/JBLjh/3/) Also, I don't know if this will help with anything, but what happens if you switch out `'click'` with `'hover'`? Does it still not work properly then?

Comment: Thanks again but it still does not work, again this is just in Chrome.

Comment: This just sucks, not sure what to do now.

Comment: Found the problem, hand nothing to do with my code. This script for the AddThis Social Plug-in cause the JQuery Code to Fail in Chrome: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-501ea3a717ca0446"></script>